# webpack / npm setup dynamic component loading

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have a single page application project that contains of a framework and some modules. The file setup is as follows:

```
_.babelrc
_package.json
_package-lock.json
_webpack.config.js
_node_modules
_src
  |_index.js
  |_index.html
  |_config.json
  |_modules
    |_example-module
      |_index.js
```

in src/index.js I load all modules specified in config.json in the specified region of index.html. This is running smoothly but there are two things I definetely want to improve:

- The main handle for all the modules must always be index.js. I want to redirect it so that other module devs can use any name they want.
- I would like to specify the dependencies of the modules separately, i.e. using a package.json/webpack.config for each module. This way, people would not have to specify their packages in the main package.json.

Is this possible to achieve using npm/webpack? If so, what would the package.json/webpack.config.js of the framework and individual packages look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it can't be achieved.As far as I know,a package only have one package.json in it.All other depens are in node_modules directory.You can let other module devs pubish their package,and in `package.json` file they can change `main` property that specify entry package file.And lastly,install their package.

Comment: The npm install will not trigger when it encounters a package.json in one of the subfolders? Placing a package.json in example-module directory broke my existing (working) setup due to babel stuff. But it does not ignore it. So there should be possibility